# Exteding properties in a java project

Tags: java, spring, maven, plugins, properties

I have a project with two properties files. Those are the config properties for different environments. As they are basically the same at the moment, I want to create a parent file property and extending it in the other ones. If I need a different value, I want to override it simply rewriting the property in the child file.
Which maven plugin or library I need to do it ?

For instance:

**Parent property file**

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

**Env1**

```
key1=valuexxx
```

**Env2**

```
key2=valueyyy
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need libraries...

You could do this way: assuming that you are putting every property in a Map, you firstly load properties from the "parent" property file, then, for every environment, you call the specific file.

By putting a new entry with an already present value into your Map, you're going to overwrite it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The fact is that I dont want to do it programmatically.

Comment: Why not, if I can ask?

Comment: Because they are used from different jars and the properties are for different tasks. I dont want to change those jars. I would like only a way to do it maybe in maven.